# send a choice to a different function in python

Tags: python, function

I am trying to build a test based game, with choices, and I was wondering if there was a way to send a choice to a specific function. This is python

for example :

```
def main():
     choice =input("'n' or 'e'")
     if choice == 'n':
          print("You walk north")
          city()
     else:
          print("You starve to death")
          near_death()
main()

def city():
     print("You finally made it to the city congrats")

city()
def near_death():
     print("Right before you black out from hunger you see an old man standing above you")

near_death()
```

is there anyway to get the if statement to go into the that it belongs too?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Your description isn't very clear. What is the expected input and output?

Comment: Define your functions BEFORE you call them in your main.

Comment: I am trying to send the choice you would make in the IF statement to the function city and the choice you would make in the else statement to the near_death function. That way as you are 'playing' the game you can have seperate outcomes without ever crossing paths.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary with members being callback functions

```
def action1():
    print "action1"
def action2():
    print "action2"
def action3():
    print "action3"
def default():
    print "default action"

def main():
    choices = {"a":action1,"b":action2,"c":action3}
    choice = raw_input("a, b, or c \n")
    action = choices.get(choice, default)
    action()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like functions?

```
global choice

def city(choice):
    if choice =="n":
        print("You finally made it to the city congrats")
    elif choice == "e":
        print("Right before you black out from hunger you see an old man standing above you")
    else:
        print("Pick an option")
        main()

def main():
    choice = input("n or e")
    city(choice)

main()
```

Comment: I think that is on the line of it. the if statement continues the story in the function city, while the else statement continues it's part of the story in the near_death function.

Comment: @Linkstus This answer gives you a beginning of what you want. The onux is on you to continue, with more functions/path choices, etc.